# How to make a Regex that chooses between 3 words?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a powershell regular expression that works and parses file names for words I need:

```
if ($_.Name -match '_(Aircraft \d+)_.+(\d{2}[a-z]{3}\d{4}).+(\d{6})') {
     '{0} - {1} - {2}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[2], $Matches[3]
```

However, I also need my expression to identify to match one of three words "FaultReports", "Logs", or "Mission". I thought that it might match these three words with a * wildcard by doing the following:

```
"if ($_.Name -match '_(Aircraft \d+)_.*(FaultReports)*(Logs)*(Mission)+(\d{2}[a-z]{3}\d{4}).+(\d{6})') {
     '{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[2], $Matches[3], $Matches[4]"
```

But, my logic errors out. **How can I get expression to identify one of the three words in the filename so my output looks like: Aircraft XX - FaultReports - 01Apr2021 - 123456?**

here is an example filename I am working with:

```
__XXXXX_XXXX_Common_XXXX_Access_KC-46 MDT_Aircraft 017_Crew Apps-FaultReports_XXXX-017-Crew Apps-FaultReports-04Dec2020-170654
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use *alternation* (`|`)** to **match *any one of* multiple subexpressions**: `(FaultReports|Logs|Mission)`

In the context of your solution (using a sample object with a `.Name` property as input):

```sh
[pscustomobject] @{
  Name = '__XXXXX_XXXX_Common_XXXX_Access_KC-46 MDT_Aircraft 017_Crew Apps-FaultReports_XXXX-017-Crew Apps-FaultReports-04Dec2020-170654'
} | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Name -match '_(Aircraft \d+)_.+-(FaultReports|Logs|Mission)-(\d{2}[a-z]{3}\d{4}).+(\d{6})') {
    '{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[2], $Matches[3], $Matches[4] 
  }
}
```

The above yields:

```
Aircraft 017 - FaultReports - 04Dec2020 - 170654
```

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/D4N2YA/1) for a detailed explanation.

---

As for **what you tried**:

While your approach of placing multiple `(...)*` subexpressions *in sequence* may *situationally* work too, it is *more permissive* than alternation and can therefore lead to *false positives*; also, it is more verbose and less efficient.

A simple example:

```
PS> '<nope>', '<foo>', '<bar>', '<foobar>', '<>' |
      ForEach-Object { $_ -match '<(foo)*(bar)*>' }

False
True
True
True  # !! '<foobar>' matched too
True  # !! '<>' matched too.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are -

```
_(Aircraft \d+)_.*(FaultReports|Logs|Mission)-(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4})-(\d{6})$
```

I tested it with javascript, it should work with powershell also.

```
    reg=/_(Aircraft \d+)_.*(FaultReports|Logs|Mission)-(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4})-(\d{6})$/

    reg.exec('__XXXXX_XXXX_Common_XXXX_Access_KC-46 MDT_Aircraft 017_Crew Apps-FaultReports_XXXX-017-Crew Apps-FaultReports-04Dec2020-170654')

Output -
    (5) ["_Aircraft 017_Crew Apps-FaultReports_XXXX-017-Crew Apps-FaultReports-04Dec2020-170654", "Aircraft 017", "FaultReports", "04Dec2020", "170654", index: 41, input: "__XXXXX_XXXX_Common_XXXX_Access_KC-46 MDT_Aircraft…_XXXX-017-Crew Apps-FaultReports-04Dec2020-170654", groups: undefined]
    0: "_Aircraft 017_Crew Apps-FaultReports_XXXX-017-Crew Apps-FaultReports-04Dec2020-170654"
    1: "Aircraft 017"
    2: "FaultReports"
    3: "04Dec2020"
    4: "170654"
```